# Laravel database connection with sql server

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I'm trying to connect to a SQL server database using larval but when I tried to test I keep getting this error I tried many many solutions.

> SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Failed to log on user 'slim'.
>   (SQL: SELECT * FROM names) (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\pointeur\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)

- I've created a simple Model :

  ```
  namespace App;

  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class Record extends Model
  {
      protected $table = 'names';
  }
  ```
- with a simple query

  ```
              $records = Record::all();

              foreach ($records as $record) {
                  echo $record->name;
              }
          ?>
  ```
- database.php

  ```
  'sqlsrv' => [
          'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
          'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'DESKTOP-ILM6T0L\SQLEXPRESS1'),
          'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'a11'),
          'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'ismail'),
          'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
          'charset' => 'utf8',
          'prefix' => '',
          ],
  ```
- .env file

  ```
  DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
  DB_HOST=DESKTOP-ILM6T0L\ISMAIL
  DB_PORT=3306
  DB_DATABASE=a11
  DB_USERNAME=slim
  DB_PASSWORD=root
  ```

(I created a user 'slim' with password 'root' )

Db name a11 it has 1 table 'names' with 1 column 'names'.

Help please I just want to connect laravel project with sql server :p

Comment: you have two different usernames which one is correct??

Comment: slim is the correct one

Comment: ok check my answer

Comment: When you created the user `slim`, did you specify the correct host to go with that user?  Generally for development, it's okay to use `%` as the host which would allow the user `slim` to connect from anywhere.

Comment: Please accept the answer or post your answer to close the question thanks :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

If you have defined everything in `.env` then you don't need to redefining the values in any file like in your `database.php`

```
'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', ''),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', ''),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix these issues using your .env file found in your root. Provide it with all your database credentials like so.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=afin
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```